# QML hide question mark from messagedialog

Tags: qt, qml

Is it possible to hide the question mark from a qml messageDialog?
My dialog:

```
MessageDialog {
    id: messageDialog
    text: "Do you want to remove the probe from the list"
    property int index: -1


    onAccepted: {
        //onAccepted is triggered twice, but we onyl want to remove the item once
        if(!removedItem){
            removedItem = true;
            applicationWindow.removeProbe(index)
            messageDialog.close()
        }
    }
}
```

The result:

[image]

The question button is leading to nowhere.

Comment: I went with a custom popup but im still interested to know if it is possible.

Comment: I added what is probably a better answer to my original post, but I can't confirm it. Please check.

Comment: Never mind... app-wide fix confirmed. Seems like the ? only appears when using `QApplication` as the base app class and/or using `QQuickView` vs. pure QML.

Answer (score 2):

***UPDATE***: I found this application attribute which looks promising. Seems to work for me for both C++ dialogs and QML `MessageDialog`.

`Qt::AA_DisableWindowContextHelpButton`

From the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ApplicationAttribute-enum) (emphasis mine):

> Disables the WindowContextHelpButtonHint by default on Qt::Sheet and Qt::Dialog widgets. This hides the ? button on Windows, which only makes sense if you use QWhatsThis functionality. This value was **added in Qt 5.10**. In Qt 6, WindowContextHelpButtonHint will not be set by default.

I set it in `main()` e.g.:

```
QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_DisableWindowContextHelpButton);
QApplication app(argc, argv);
```

Incidentally, I found that `MessageDialog` created from pure-QML `Window` or `ApplicationWindow` (loaded directly as a `Component` into a `QmlEngine` and displayed that way) doesn't have the context help button. But one from inside a `QQuickView` does. So if using only `QGuiApplication` then this shouldn't be needed.

***ORIGINAL***:

There is no API available in the `QtQuick.Dialogs` version of `MessageDialog` to control the window flags.  (QML can be frustrating like that, IMHO.)

The [Qt Labs version](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-platform-messagedialog.html) does have a way to specify [window flags](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WindowType-enum) (in the base `Dialog` type). So to exclude the `?` one would remove the `Qt::WindowContextHelpButtonHint` from default flags or set your own flags specifically.

Something like this should work (not tested in QML but this is essentially what I do for `QDialog`):

```
import Qt.labs.platform 1.1
MessageDialog {
  flags: Qt.Dialog | Qt.CustomizeWindowHint | Qt.WindowTitleHint | Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint | Qt.WindowSystemMenuHint
}
```

But note that the Labs version comes with its own caveats as described in their docs.